# Is there any setting in Xcode to have all autocomplete code follow a different curly bracket style?

Tags: xcode, settings, xcode4.5, indentation, curly-braces

Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style), Xcode defaults to using the K&R brace/indentation style. It looks like this:

```
- (void) someFunction {
    if (condition) {
        // do this
    } else
        // do that;
    }
}
```

I've grown up with a strong preference for [Allman style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style), which looks like this:

```
- (void) someFunction
{
    if (condition)
    {
        // do this
    }
    else
    {
        // do that
    }
}
```

It's not too much of a chore just to return the bracket of a code-completed statement to the next line, but if I could tell Xcode to do this for me, it would save me a lot of meticulous click-and-return'ing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can remove the K&R braced code snippets, but you could simply [create your own](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/CreatingaCustomCodeSnippet/CreatingaCustomCodeSnippet.html) Allman-style snippets and add them to the Xcode "Code Snippet Library". It's a cumbersome solution, but it works.

So, when writing your snippets, you can use the `<#` and `#>` to delimit your expressions. Thus:

```
if (<#condition#>)
{
    <#statements-if-true#>
}
else
{
    <#statements-if-false#>
}
```

Then drag and drop that onto your snippet library:

[image]

And give it a meaningful name and shortcut:

[image]

Now when you start typing, you'll leverage the new snippet:

[image]

Go ahead and give your snippet a unique completion shortcut if you want to make disambiguation even easier.

There are more effective uses of the snippet library, but it can be used to address your problem.